# How do I save a return list to table asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, memorystream

I have a method that reads an excel file which user can upload via the front end - see below:

```
public async Task<List<User>> Upload(IFormFile file)
{
   string webRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
   var uploads = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "upload");
   var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
   using (var filesStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads,file.FileName), 
   FileMode.Create))
   {
      files[0].CopyTo(filesStream);
   }
   var list = new List<User>();
   using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
   {
      await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
      using(var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
      {
         ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
         var rowcount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
         for(int row =3; row <= rowcount; row++)
         {
           list.Add(new User
           {
              UserName = worksheet.Cells[row,1].Value.ToString().Trim(),
              Email = worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value.ToString().Trim(),
              FirstName = worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value.ToString().Trim(),
              Surname = worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value.ToString().Trim(),
              PhoneNumber = worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Value.ToString().Trim(),
           }); 
         }
      }
   }
   return list;
}
```

The above code works fine but my problem now is that I need to loop through that list and save the data to the user table. So my question here is: How can I use the **return list** to save the data to the user model/table something like

```
_db.user.add(list)
_db.savechanges()
return View();
```

Comment: What is `_db`? In other words, which ORM (+ version) is this?

Comment: _db is entity framework core or dependency injection (ApplicationDBContext) so I'm trying to write into mySql database.

Comment: Then I assume that these lower-case methods don't exist. Please be accurate when posting code. Also, please add a tag for the EF version you use. Try to ask questions that don't require too many assumptions. That said, I assume you should use `AddRange`.

Comment: You haven't work with asp dot net core have you? I appreciate you want to help but if you have no idea then please pass along rather than making it seems like the question is out of place which isn't. If you have work with the tags mentioned then you would have knowledge of _db because it's a common knowledge as 'hello world'

Comment: Please don't do this. The code has nothing to do with ASP.Net core. It's all about *propbably* Entity Framework and you don't seem to realize that it matters very much which EF version is used. With EF, AddRange is the answer. Not a foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming _db is your context, I think you can do a foreach to save the data:

```
foreach(var user in list){
  _db.user.Add(user);
}
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Remember to use the await operator to call the funcion. var list = await Upload(file);

Comment: `AddRange` should be used. Each `Add` call also calls `DetectChanges` internally which may take a considerable amount of time when there are many items. `AddRange` only does that once.

Comment: AddRange is available since EF 6.2.0 version. In this version it can be used instead a foreach.